# Service desk create request - raiseOnBehalfOf could not be found

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

When  I send a GET request to JIRA service desk cloud ***rest/servicedeskapi/servicedesk/{id}/requesttype/{id}/field***
in the response I can see `"canRaiseOnBehalfOf": true,`.

But in the Post request if I add 'raiseOnBehalfOf' ***(rest/servicedeskapi/request)***

```
{
"serviceDeskId": "1",
"requestTypeId": "2",
"requestFieldValues": {
"summary": "Request raised via service REST API",
"description": "test.",
"raiseOnBehalfOf" : "dummy@gmail.com"
}
}
```

then it fails with  **400 error**

```
{
"errorMessage": "Unable to create request because of theses errors : The field 'raiseOnBehalfOf' could not be found.",
"i18nErrorMessage": {
"i18nKey": "sd.request.create.error.failed.msg",
"parameters": [
"The field 'raiseOnBehalfOf' could not be found."
]
}
}
```

Could someone please give a clue  why it is happening so?

Comment: Understood the issue. I was putting 'raiseOnBehalfOf ' inside requestFieldValues but it should be outside

Answer (score 3):

Understood the issue. I was putting 'raiseOnBehalfOf ' inside requestFieldValues but it should be outside

```
{
"serviceDeskId": "1",
"requestTypeId": "1",
"requestFieldValues": {
"summary": "Request raised via service REST API",
"description": "test."
},
"raiseOnBehalfOf" : "dummy@gmail.com"
```

}